# ¿Cómo crear una lista en base a solicitar datos de teclado en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa para armar una lista en base a datos solicitados por teclado.

La lista misma se va llenando de datos conforme se ingresen por teclado.

El problema es que no sé como hacer para que, una vez finalice el ingreso de datos por teclado apretando la tecla "Enter", estos mismos datos se almacenen en una nueva lista para conservar los datos ingresados. O sea, crear una lista en base a los datos ingresados por teclado y guardarla para luego repetir el procedimiento y así crear diferentes listas en base a datos solicitados por teclado.

Desde ya muchas gracias por ver mi problema, saludos.

```
invitados = []

 nombres = input("ingrese un nombre para la lista de invitados: ")

 while nombres != "":
     invitados.append(nombres)
     nombres = input("ingrese un nombre para la lista de invitados:")

 print(invitados)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, Así como esta tu pregunta parece una tarea y aquí no hacemos tareas, podemos ayudarte si muestras lo que has intentado y describes cual es tu error puntual que tienes. Para elaborar una buena pregunta puedes leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/477940/edit) tu pregunta las veces que sea necesarias para agregar más detalles :D

Comment: Directamente te puedo decir que hagas `[input("ingrese un datos separados por comas").split(",") for _ in range(10)]` pero no sé si se ajuste a lo que quieres, nosotros no somos adivinos para saber que código tienes, por favor considera agregar el avance que llevas.

Comment: agrega un `if nombres.strip() == "": break` y todo se soluciona

Answer (score 0):

Estos códigos permiten crear una lista por teclado de forma simple, llamando a la función cuántas veces se precise. Espero sea de utilidad.

```
def lista_invitados():
    invitados = input('Ingrese el nombre del 
invitado o "end" para cerrar: ')
    lista =[]
    while invitados != "end":
        lista.append(invitados)
        invitados = input('Ingrese el nombre del 
invitado o "end" para cerrar: ')
    
    return lista

print()
print()     
print("Los invitados a la fiesta son: 
",lista_invitados())
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor agrega una breve explicación del código para así saber que es lo que hace y también indica cual era el problema y como lo solucionas, mira [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

Supongo que lo que quieres hacer es crear listas de invitados que se vayan guardando. Para esto, te propongo guardarlas en un fichero añadiendo la fecha de creación de las lista para diferenciarlas.

He comentado el código, si aún así hay algo que no entiendes o no es lo que buscabas, coméntame.

Se importa el modulo 'os' para creacion de ficheros y el 'datetime' para diferenciar dia y hora de ficheros.

Luego se crea una excepcion en la función open() por si ya estaba creado el texto sólo adjuntar.

A la hora de introducir 'nombre' he creado un bucle hasta que 'nombre' sea 'fin' y luego lo eliminamos con `lista.pop()`. En fin, espero que te sirva de algo

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
hoy = datetime.now()
try: #creamos un fichero y si está creado, salta excepción.
    txt = open('inv.txt','x',encoding='utf8')
except FileExistsError:
    print('Fichero ya existe, crea una nueva lista de invitados.')
    txt = open('inv.txt','a',encoding='utf8') #simplemente adjuntamos en el fichero

lista_invitados = [] #creamos lista
crea = ''
while crea! = 'fin':
    crea=input('Ingresa invitado o escribe fin para terminar lista: ')
    lista_invitados.append(crea) 
lista_invitados.pop()#eliminamos el ultimo nombre que es 'fin'
txt.write('Lista invitados con fecha: \n{}\n {}'.format(hoy,lista_invitados))#adjuntamos el fichero con la fecha de la nueva lista invitados
txt.close()#cerramos fichero
```

Comment: Lo probé por supuesto y funciona perfectamente, tuve un error de indentacion al final en las últimas 3 líneas ya está arreglado. Mis disculpas

Comment: Esto no responde al problema, en ninguna parte se ha pedido guardar los datos en un archivo de texto, además se quiere parar al resignar *Enter*, no al teclear fin. No estas obligado a responder todas las preguntas, tómate tu tiempo.